# Disable touch-pad while typing doesn't work in Lubuntu

Tags: lubuntu, touchpad, lxde, autostart

Disable touch-pad while typing doesn't work in the latest Lubuntu. So far I tried two solutions, non of them worked:

1. Adding `syndaemon -d -t` line to `~/.config/lxsession/Lubuntu/autostart` and restart. ([source](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Mouse))
2. https://askubuntu.com/a/369366/496493

Comment: It works in Ubuntu Mate.  Mate can go pretty low in memory usage too.  I love this feature.  (I used to be lubuntu)

Comment: Have you tried **Touchpad-indicator**? Check my answer [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/798967/308164).

Comment: I tried it and it works, thanks :-) you may reply an answer here to receive the buonty

Comment: to make it autostart, it is enough to add the program to session start up. the fix you mention didnt work for me

Comment: @luchonacho answer this question to get the buonty!

Comment: forgot about it! thks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Touchpad-Indicator** does the job. It is not available from official Ubuntu repositories, so you need to add one manually. To ge the latest version, run the following in a terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:atareao/atareao
```

To install, run:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install touchpad-indicator
```

To disable touch-pad while typing, open the program and select the respective option from Preferences -> Actions.

Finally, don't forget to add the app to the startup list. You can do this within the same program, from Preferences -> General options tab. If that does not work, you might need to add it manually through your settings menu (in Lubuntu, it should be under Preferences -> Desktop Session Settings).

PS: some users mention a restart to make the program work.

Comment: This package no longer exists.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the `synclient` command:

```
synclient TouchPadOff=1
synclient TouchPadOff=0
```

`TouchPadOff=1` to disable touch pad. `TouchPadOff=0` to enable touch pad.

Then, I have added these two commands in hotkeys to make enable and disable tasks easy. It works fine.

Answer (score 0):

**For Lubuntu 19:**

Click on "Start" -> Preferences -> LXQt Settings -> LXQt Configuration Center

Click on Session Settings

Select Autostart in the left panel

Click on Add

In the box that open enter any name like Touchpad disable.

In the Command type: xinput set-prop 13 "Device Enabled" 0

In my case the touchpad id is 13.

Find your device id in the terminal by entering the following in the terminal:  xinput list

Reboot